# Using django as an ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

I am exploring using django as an ORM and have a basic question, using eclipse, I was able to load django, create a project, setup my database connection in the settings.py file and run the

```
manage.py inspectdb
```

command which created successfully the models.py file  so now i am left with the structure (familiar to all)

ProjectName

---ProjectName

------settings.py

------urls.py

------wsgi.py

---manage.py

---models.py

now the way i wish to use django is just a better way to interface with my database created in the models.py (and not as a webservice, or restful api, or anything like that)

when i try some simple code like:

```
import models
import django
django.setup()
my_model = models.SomeDefinedModel.objects.all()
for mod in my_model:
  print mod
```

I get some exception:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

All i *want* to do is query the table behind the database that the

```
SomeDefinedModel
```

is build from (using the inspectdb command)

is this possible?  I've been searching on the internet forever, and cant seem to find a way to use this as an access layer.

Thanks -

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely annoying to do. I have done it a few times and only for scripts that managed my data that is used in a django app for me. It feels really hacky and if all you want is the ORM, I wouldn't recommend using Django as this will load all this other stuff you don't need. If you just want an ORM, go with SQLAlchemy.

If that still didn't convince you, here is how I did it for a daemon:

What you have to do first is set an environment variable that tells django where to find your settings, then you have to tell django to set up. Then you can start using the Django stuff. After you do all of that, you can start importing your models. 
Here is an example of how I did that:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourproject.settings")
import django
django.setup()
#Rest of your code
```

**Again, if you aren't building a website or webapp, I heavily advise against using Django. This will make your application 100x bigger when you only want to use 1% of django.** SQLAlchemy may even be a better ORM. I've been playing around with it more in the last couple of days and I feel like I can write more complex SQL. Link to SQLAlchemy: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Comment: Agreed. The Django ORM brings all sorts of goodies with it, almost none of which you need. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: great thanks, i will check it out!